# "Too low for the price" or "too less for the price"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, adjectives, comparatives

> 1. Too low for the price
> 2. Too less for the price

Please suggest which one is correct grammatically.

Scenarios:

1. The cost for 15 minute show was Rupees 50. It is too low for the price.
2. I went to the market to buy bananas. The cost of 10 bananas was Rupees 100. It is too less for the price.

Comment: Could you please use the phrase (either one) in a sentence and provide the intended meaning with at least one additional full sentence?

Comment: Also please visit http://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: (1/2) This is dialect-dependent: in "Standard" American and British English one never modifies "less" with words like "too" or "very", but in (subcontinental) Indian English one does it all the time (or so I have observed).

Comment: (2/2) If you are trying to convey what I think you are, the preferred expression in StdAmEng would be "Too *little* for the price."

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure, without the context, what *Too low for the price* would mean, but I can think of no contexts in which *too less* would be used.